# Given a vector, return a list of all combinations up to size n

Tags: r, combinations

I'm trying to write a function in R that, given a vector and a maximum size n, will return all the combinations of elements from that vector, up to size n.

E.g.:

```
multi_combn(LETTERS[1:3], 2)
```

Would yield:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "B"

[[3]]
[1] "C"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[6]]
[1] "B" "C"
```

I've figured out an inelegant way to run `combn` for each size up to n, but I can't seem to combine the results into a single list.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
multi_combn <- function(dat, n) {
    unlist(lapply(1:n, function(x) combn(dat, x, simplify=F)), recursive=F)
}
```

which returns

```
> multi_combn(LETTERS[1:3], 2)
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "B"

[[3]]
[1] "C"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[6]]
[1] "B" "C"
```

Comment: +1, I was on that track. The `simplify=F` was the part I couldn't figure out.  nice work.

Comment: Yep, there is some juggling with `simplify` and `recursive`. The last one took me quite a few seconds to remember..

Comment: +1 and a slightly more compact version: `do.call(c, lapply(1:n, combn, x=dat, simplify=FALSE))`.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here are a couple of completely different approaches:

**Alternative 1:**

```
multi_combn <- function(X) {
    ii <- do.call(expand.grid, 
                  replicate(length(X), c(FALSE, TRUE), simplify=FALSE))[-1,]
    apply(ii, 1, function(i) X[i])
}
multi_combn(LETTERS[1:3])
```

**Alternative 2:** (I don't usually like obfuscated code, but this function's an exception.)

```
multi_combn <- function(X) {
    sapply(seq_len(2^(length(X)) - 1), 
           FUN = function(n) {
               X[as.logical(rawToBits(as.raw(n)))]
           })
}    
multi_combn(LETTERS[1:3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same format as your desired output, but maybe close enough?

```
multi_combn <- function(dat, n) {
    lapply(seq_len(n), function(x) t(combn(dat, x))) 
}

> dat <- LETTERS[1:3]
> multi_combn(dat,3)
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "A" 
[2,] "B" 
[3,] "C" 

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "B"  "C" 

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"
```

Comment: Close.  I'd really like to make a list with one entry per combination, so I can iterate over the list.